# Select a WebElement "View Seats Button" of a bus with least fare and departure time between 8:00 PM and 10:00 PM

Tags: java, loops, selenium, arraylist, datetime-format

I have to click on view seats button of a bus with lowest fare and departure time between 8:00 PM and 10:00 PM. I was able to check if the three conditions are met. But after the 3 conditions are met, it is not going inside the if loop and clicking on the view seats button.It is just going to the next index. My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BookTicketTime1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //page1
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtSource")).sendKeys("Vizag");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtDestination")).sendKeys("Vijayawada");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'rbcal_txtOnwardCalendar']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[@id = 'searchBtn']")).click();

    //Page 2
try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='busIcon busDataBlock icon-Plus_Icon']")).isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='busIcon busDataBlock icon-Plus_Icon']")).click();

        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("element not displayed ");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   

    //Get time and select time after 8:00 PM        
    ArrayList<WebElement> timeList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    timeList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.className("DepartureTime")));    
    int timeN = timeList.size();

    //Remove "Starts At"
    String First = timeList.get(0).getText();       
    if(First.equals("Starts At")){
       timeList.remove(0);                         
    }

    ArrayList<String> fareAry = new ArrayList<String>();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    Date time = null;
    int index = 0;
    Date eightT = null;
    String eight = "8:00 PM";
    eightT = df.parse(eight);
        for (WebElement t : timeList) {                             
                   String timeString = t.getText();           

                    try {
                        time = df.parse(timeString);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }           

                    if(time.after(eightT)){                                                      
                        String fareText = t.getText();
                        String fare = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+fareText+"']/../../../..//span[@class='Fare']")).getText();
                        fareAry.add(fare);                                                                              
                    }
                    index++;            

                }
            System.out.println("Total buses: "+timeN);
            System.out.println("Number of buses after 8:00 PM are "+fareAry.size());
            System.out.println(" Fares of buses after 8:00 PM are "+fareAry);

    // Convert String arraylist to Integer arraylist

            ArrayList <Integer> fareIntAry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (String farevalue : fareAry) {
                try {
                    fareIntAry.add(Integer.parseInt(farevalue));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Number not found");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Integer Fare arraylist "+fareIntAry);

    // Get lowest fare
            Collections.sort(fareIntAry);
            System.out.println("Sorted fares "+fareIntAry);
            System.out.println("Lowest fare is "+fareIntAry.get(0));
            int lFare = fareIntAry.get(0);
            String lowestFare = String.valueOf(lFare);



//Click on Viewseats button of bus with lowest fare and departure time after 8:00pm

    List<WebElement> faresList = new ArrayList ();
    faresList = driver.findElements(By.className("Fare"));
    ArrayList<WebElement> selectedTime = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    selectedTime.addAll(timeList);
    int index5 = 0;
    String ten = "10:00 PM";
    Date tenT = null;
    tenT = df.parse(ten);
    for (WebElement fare : faresList) { 

        String fText = fare.getText();
        String tiS = timeList.get(index5).getText();
        time = df.parse(tiS);

        if ((fText.equals(lowestFare))&&(time.after(eightT))&&(time.before(tenT))) {                                                

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='"+lowestFare+"']/../../../..//a[text()='"+tiS+"']/../../../../button[@class='viewSeatsBtn']")).click();

          }

         index5++;
     }





}
}
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.
I hope I am clear. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

I found my mistake.

```
tenT = df.parse(eight);
```

Here, I have to give

```
tenT = df.parse(ten);
```

This is the reason, why I am getting false for the last condition.

Comment: If the code doesn't go inside the `if` it means one or more of your conditions isn't met. Check each one of them separately.

Comment: I used debug to check each of them separately, but even if the conditions are met, it is not going into the if loop. I even used nested if loop also to  with conditions least fare and departure time after 8:00 PM. If the condition is true, then it is going to the next if loop with condition  departure time before 10:00 PM. Even if this 10:00PM condition is true also, it is not going into the loop to click on the view button.

Comment: If it doesn't go into the `if` the condition is not true. The alternative is bug in `if` implementation witch is unlikely. Try `boolean b = time.before(tenT)` and check `b` value (it will be false).

Comment: even if fare was least and time was 9:45 PM, it didn't go into the if loop.

Comment: @ guy, I have modified my code as per your suggestion and you were right. Thank you. I posted my modified code and output in my question. Could you please help me with how I can go to the next least fare and do the same. I am new to java. Thank you.

Comment: @guy, I changed the date and out of the output, which I got,"389 09:45 PM a true b false" is an error because, the lowest fare there was, 389 and time, 9:45 PM falls between 8 and 10 pm. but why did I get an anomaly like that?

Comment: I see you found the answer. Good luck.